# Metric for local texture similarity

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I'm working on the following classification task:
Take two patches of an image and compare for illumination invariant texture similarity.
There are a couple of features which could be used to compare two image patches for texture similarity. Candidates are Local Binary Patterns (LBP) or Histograms of Oriented Gradients (HOG). Both generate a feature vector. What I'm looking for is a good metric which can be used to compare two feature vectors for texture similarity as described above.

Comment: L2, cosine, HISTCMP_HELLINGER

Comment: training a 2-class SVM on distances(same/not-same) will work even better, also funny kernels to try, like intersection or kmod

Comment: Illumination invariant screams for HSV color space; just drop the V :)

Comment: EMD is quite robust for histogram comparison